# POST variable doesn't exist after AJAX is used to filter select options

Tags: php, ajax

I have a working form with a `POST` method and this form contains the following select dropdown:

```
<div id="typeselect">
<select name="type" id="type" style="float:left;margin-right:100px;">
<option>Choose Surgery type</option>
<?php
$spec_res=mysql_query("select * from operation_list order by Narrative") or die(mysql_error());
while($spec_row=mysql_fetch_array($spec_res)){
    echo "<option>".$spec_row['Narrative']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
</div>
```

It works fine, and on the action page, `$_POST['type']` has the correct value of whatever is selected.

However, I've added another dropdown with `id='specialty'` that is used to dynamically filter the options available in the 'type' dropdown using Ajax. Filtering is based on a column named 'Specialty1' in the same 'operation_list' database table. This works too, but then when I submit the form, `$_POST['type']` has no value! Can someone tell me what I'm doign wrong? Here's the Ajax function and the PHP file it points to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getTypes(str)
{

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("typeselect").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","showtypes.php?specialty="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

And showtypes.php:

```
<?php
//dbconnection here

$specialty=$_GET['specialty'];

?>

<select name="type" id="type" style="float:left;margin-right:100px;">
<option>Choose Surgery type</option>
<?php
$spec_res=mysql_query("select * from operation_list where Specialty1='$specialty' order by Narrative") or die(mysql_error());
while($spec_row=mysql_fetch_array($spec_res)){
    echo "<option>".$spec_row['Narrative']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

So, to sum up, why doesn't `$_POST['type']` exist after I use Ajax to alter the select options, and what can I do to fix this while keeping all the functionality?

EDIT: Never mind the comment that was in the Ajax function, it was obsolete and I had forgotten to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what your problem is, but I think you could simplify it a lot if you used [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#type').change(function() {
        $('#typeselect').load('showtypes.php', { specialty: $(this).val() });
    });
</script>
```

- See http://api.jquery.com/change/ for information on the change event.
- See http://api.jquery.com/load/ for information of the Ajax load function.

Answer (score 0):

Better yet,

jQuery-ized function:

```
function getTypes(str,input_form){
    $.post("showtyps.php?specialty="+str, $("#"+input_form).serialize(), 
    function(data){
        // This happens when the data is loaded
        $("#typeselect").html(data);
    });
}
```

The difference being you will also need to pass the id of the form along with the first argument.

If you would rather do things one field at a time, you can replace

```
$("#"+input_form).serialize()
```

with

```
{
    'postvariablename' : $("#idofelement").serialize(),
    'postvariable2name' : $("#idof2ndelement").serialize()
}
```

And so on...

You will of course need to include jQuery first in order for it to work, but I highly recommend using it in these types of cases, for the utmost in cross compatibility.